# Angular showring default page. How to fix?

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm new to Angular, learn from official documentation and was making with tutorial authorization page with FireBase.
Currently when I launch ng serve command the default page opens. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrect. Can somebody help me please?

Git: https://github.com/TyroniUA/authtest

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './components/signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/signup/signup.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { AuthGuard } from "./shared/guard/auth.guard";
import { SecureInnerPagesGuard } from "./shared/guard/secure-inner-pages.guard";

import { VerifyEmailComponent } from './components/verify-email/verify-email.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SigninComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard]},
  { path: 'register-user', component: SignupComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard]},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard] },
  { path: 'verify-email-address', component: VerifyEmailComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard] }
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

UPD 1: 
it looks like this. I successfully registered or logged in with Google, and saw the dashboard, but default page always there :) 
[image]

UPD 2: 
[image]

Comment: try removing the "/"  in your empty route : { path: ''", redirectTo: 'sign-in', pathMatch: 'full'}

Comment: Still nothing. I removed it and still getting a default page.

Comment: @Volodymyr Rudov-Tsymbalist you noticed or not I  m not sure but you need to add here page name ```path: ''```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cloned your project and the issue was with the initialization of the firebase app in your app.module.ts . due to it your secure-innerpage class was'nt able to get the token and checked user status.

for that I made two changes

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp({     //change 1 Initialized app
    apiKey: "Add your credentials here",
    authDomain: "Add your credentials here",
    databaseURL: "Add your credentials here",
    projectId: "Add your credentials here",
    storageBucket: "Add your credentials here",
    messagingSenderId: "Add your credentials here",
    appId: "Add your credentials here",
    measurementId: "Add your credentials here"
  }),
  AngularFireAuthModule,
  AngularFirestoreModule,
],
providers: [AuthService,AngularFirestore], //change 2 Injected AngularFireStore
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Ideally you should save your credentials to enviroment valiable in enviroment.ts file and initiallize app with it here.

Also your firebase credentials will be found under project settings>credentials in your firebase console.

It works perfectly fine for me after these changes, I hope it works for you too!!

Comment: Hi, thanks you for fix. It made some progress, for sure, but not exactly how it suppose to look. Currently I have default page + plain text version of signing page. Post a picture above.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention please remove all the default code in the app.component.html and replace it with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` . this will solve the issue

Comment: Thank you. Also, as far as I understand - bootstrap doesn't work. Yesterday I have an issue of 2 scss files conflict, so I removed default from the angular.json - maybe it's a reason? 

Does it look better and correct in your version?

Comment: It is plain form in my outcome too. But the bootsrap is installed and working correctly.The reason you are not able to see styling is your html.I suppose you have took template of form from some blog for adding authentication with firebase. you need to change your html classes name for bootstrap to work. For instance in your sign-in component's html file replace button's class name `btn btnPrimary` to `btn btn-primary`. In the same way carry on with all classes. Use bootstrap documentation [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: If the answer satisfy your purpose please mark it as accepted answer. An upvote is also appreciated. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you, I voted but it says doesn't count publicly as my lvl is low :)